Permutation in String: Why my code is giving false positives?
I am trying to solve LeetCode problem Permutation in String:

Given two strings s1 and s2, return true if s2 contains a permutation of s1, or false otherwise.
In other words, return true if one of s1's permutations is the substring of s2.
Example 1:
Input: s1 = "ab", s2 = "eidbaooo"
Output: true
Explanation: s2 contains one permutation of s1 ("ba").

My approach is to create a permutation method which generates all possible permutations for s1 and stores all permutations in a HashSet and then the CheckInclusion method checks whether the s2 contains any of the permutations of s1 or not.
This is my code:
class Solution {
    public static final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    public static void permutations(String str , String ans){
        //abc //""
        if(str.length() == 0){
            set.add(ans);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            String newStr = str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i+1);
            permutations(newStr,ans + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    public boolean checkInclusion(String s1, String s2) {
        permutations(s1 , "");
        for(String s : set){
            if(s2.contains(s)){
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
}

This above code is not passing the test with this input:
s1 = "abc"
s2 = "ccccbbbbaaaa"

The correct answer is false but my code is reported to return true, but I don't know why that is happening. When I debug it, it returns false for that input.

What is the description of the task? "Permutation in String" is not revealing much about what your code is supposed to do.

I guess that you are running multiple cases one after the other, but don't reset your hashmap in between, so that entries from one run leak into the next, giving false positives.

@trincot the question is this : Given two strings s1 and s2, return true if s2 contains a permutation of s1, or false otherwise.
In other words, return true if one of s1's permutations is the substring of s2.

I see, that is a LeetCode problem. Added a link to the code challenge and quoted its description in your question.

The problem is not with the specific test case you have mentioned, but with the fact that your implementation is not pure. It mutates a static field, and silently assumes that it is empty when checkInclusion is called. But this is not the case when checkInclusion is called several times with several different inputs. And so, after some calls of checkInclusion there will be entries in this field that were already there and that just happen to be a substring of s2, giving a potentially false positive.
The shortest fix is to add this statement at the top of your function, just before permutation is called:
set.clear();

Now you'll get the expected result. But you'll hit a different problem: although your algorithm returns the correct result, it is not efficient. For larger inputs it will take too much time and memory. For instance, if s1 has 60 characters, the number of permutations to generate is more than there are atoms in the observable universe, so don't expect your set will be able to collect those, never mind how long it would take to produce those permutations.
Efficient approach
A completely different algorithm is needed. Try to think of ways to do this without having to generate all permutations.
Two hints:

 letter counters


 sliding window algorithm

If with those hints you can't make it work, here is a spoiler solution:

     public boolean checkInclusion(String s1, String s2) {
         int n = s1.length();
         int m = s2.length();
         // Boundary case:
         if (m < n) {
             return false;
         }
         // Count how many we have of each character in s1
         int[] counter = new int[26]; // For each English lowercase letter
         for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             counter[s1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
         }
         // Count how many not-matching characters we have in the first n characters of s2
         int notMatched = 0;
         for (int right = 0; right < n; right++) {
             if (counter[s2.charAt(right) - 'a']-- == 0) {
                 // This is a nonmatching character
                 notMatched++;
             }
         }
         // Slide a window of size n over s2, doing the bookkeeping
         //   of how many we have of each in that window
         for (int right = n; right < m; right++) {
             if (notMatched == 0) {
                 return true;
             }
             if (++counter[s2.charAt(right - n) - 'a'] == 0) {
                 // This nonmatch slides OUT of the window
                 notMatched--;
             }
             if (counter[s2.charAt(right) - 'a']-- == 0) {
                 // This nonmatch slides INTO the window
                 notMatched++;
             }
         }
         return notMatched == 0;
     }


with your hints i solved my question on my own and it worked .

Glad to hear! Good job!
